# Android: Documentation for using NdkMediaDrm with PlayReady

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, drm, playready

I wonder whether anyone has tried using `NdkMediaDrm` with PlayReady? If so, is there any documentation available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NdkMediaDrm` API is designed for interacting with DRM technologies built into the Android operating system by the device's manufacturer. While there are Android devices that do include PlayReady (e.g. most Samsung devices), I lack information on whether they expose PlayReady through this API.

If you are simply looking to enable PlayReady playback on Android, you will want to use the [Microsoft PlayReady Client SDK for Android](http://www.microsoft.com/playready/features/ClientOptions.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised it wasn't a standard thing. I know that the [ADT-1](https://developer.android.com/tv/adt-1/index.html) devices expose playready through this API, are you aware of any documentation for this?

Comment: No, I do not have any familiarity with those devices.